# Using source command in bash

Tags: bash, jessie-lite

As described here [Is there a difference between “.” and “source” in bash, after all?](https://askubuntu.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F182012%2Fis-there-a-difference-between-and-source-in-bash-after-all%3Flq%3D1), I'm trying to set-up this approach in a simple script without success so far (Raspian Jessie). When using the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /media/usb0/tmp/NT20.sh
echo $var1
```

as expected it lists the content of the file. However when using this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /media/usb0/tmp/NT20.sh
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
. /media/usb0/tmp/NT20.sh
```

I get this error returned: "source not found". There must be something quite obvious that I don't understand. Or is the source command not support by this flavor of bash on Jessie Lite?

NT20.sh file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=10
```

This idea behind this is to be able to store a persistent variable and read it when needed.
Thank you for help.

Comment: This is not a Pi question. `source` will include the contents of a file in a script and execute it - not list it. The error presumably comes from a failed execute of some code.

Comment: Well I made another test. What is not reported here is that the exit command terminates NT20.sh which causes the entire script to end prematurely. AND source command is not supported only the notation with a dot .
In other words with so few lines I had two bugs ;)
So it is fine know I have a way to manage persistent data with batch

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem [cannot be reproduced](http://tpcg.io/ObOAIn).